# How to implement keyboards shortcuts on a winform with a CefSharp control?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-events, cefsharp

When i implement a KeyDown event on my Form, the event will never trigger. I've found posts saying i need to implement the CefSharp.IKeyboardHandler interface but i don't understand how i should implement this. can Someone give me an example of how to implement this or suggest another fix i could use to bypass this problem?

I'm using CefSharp version 49.0.1 and .Net framework 4.0.

i'm trying to implement keyboard shortcuts into my winform application and have KeyPreview on the form set to True. The problem i'm noticing is that it never triggers the KeyDown event of the form when i go over it with the debugger turned on.

**This is the code i used to initiate the event on the mainForm:**

```
    public ChromiumWebBrowser browser;

    //is called in the constructor of the class
    public void InitBrowser()
    {
        Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings());
        browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("www.google.com")
        {
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
        };
        this.Controls.Add(browser);
    }

    //trying to open up a messagebox when the "ctrl+w" keys are pressed 
    //whilst the form is active
    private void MCMainForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Control && e.KeyCode.ToString() == "W")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("test");
        }
    }
```

Comment: The version you are using is old and unsupported,  you'll have to work out the specifics yourself.  Implement IKeyboardHandler, check modifiers and windowskeycode to determine if your combination has been pressed. Make sure you assign your handler instance to the browser KeyboardHandler property.

Comment: You can probably modify https://github.com/gam2125/browser/blob/fb919124233554021ac903e6299f7995f79f0ba7/src/Handlers/KeyboardHandler.cs#L8 as a starting point

Comment: @amaitland alright thank you i'll try that and see if that can fix my problem